# How can I show data in DataGrid when I press button in WPF Mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to make the data appear on the data grid when I press the button using MVVM.
When you invoke a method directly from the constructor, the data appears, but when you press the button, the data does not appear.

this is my code

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    static string strConn = "";
    MySqlConnection con;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet ds;
    Boolean dataOnOff = false;
    public ObservableCollection<Students> _students = new ObservableCollection<Students>();
    public ObservableCollection<Students> Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set
        {
            if (_students == value) return;
            _students = value;
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {



        ReadCommand = new RelayCommand(DoRead);
    }


    public void FillList(object param)
    {
        if (dataOnOff == true)
        {
            try
            {

                con = new MySqlConnection(strConn);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from student", con);
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "student");

                if (_students == null)
                    _students = new ObservableCollection<Students>();

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    _students.Add(new Students
                    {
                        grade = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                        cclass = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString()),
                        name = Convert.ToString(dr[2].ToString()),
                        no = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3].ToString()),
                        score = Convert.ToString(dr[4].ToString())
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            finally
            {
                ds = null;
                adapter.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
            dataOnOff = false;
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public RelayCommand ReadCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand AddUserCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand DeleteUserCommand { get; set; }


    public void DoRead(object param)
    {
        FillList(param);
        dataOnOff = true;
        MessageBox.Show("s");
    }

}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="610"  Padding="10">
            <DataGrid Width="590" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="studentDataGrid" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding students, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="grade" Binding="{Binding grade,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="class" Binding="{Binding cclass, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding name, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="no" Binding="{Binding no, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="score" Binding="{Binding score, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Border>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="180"  Padding="0">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="ReadBtn" Content="READ" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="10,15,10,15"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding ReadCommand}"/>
                <Button x:Name="InsertBtn" Content="INSERT" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="10"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button x:Name="UpdateBtn" Content="UPDATE" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="10"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button x:Name="DeleteBtn" Content="DELETE" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="10"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>


    </DockPanel>
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

I want to make the data visible in the data grid when the button is pressed.
How can I fix it??

Comment: Have you already tried anything? What *particular* issues do you encounter?

Comment: Why would the data appear when you press a `Button` using this code? The `DoRead` method doesn't seem to do anything meaningful.

Comment: Call 'FillList' method inside 'DoRead'

Comment: @mm8 I think it's uploaded because it's not in the process of modifying it.Originally, there was a FilLlist in the DoRead method.

Comment: Originally? And now? What do you expect to happen when you execute this code?

Comment: @mm8 I revised it to the code I had at the time. Thank you for letting me know the problem.

Comment: @mm8 no....I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: @HyunBin: You still haven't answered my question about what you expect to happen when you what.

Comment: @mm8 
I expected the data stored in the database to be represented in the data grid when I pressed the Read button while there was no representation in the data grid until the button was pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following.

1. Call `OnPropertyChanged` in `Students` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Students> Students
{
    get { return _students; }
    set
    {
        if (_students == value) return;
        _students = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Students));
    }
}
```

2. Set `dataOnOff` variable to `true` in ViewModel constructor:

```cs
public MyViewModel()
{
    dataOnOff = true;
    ReadCommand = new RelayCommand(DoRead);
}
```

3. Call `FillList` method in `DoRead`, as mentioned in comments:

```
public void DoRead(object param)
{
    FillList(param);
    dataOnOff = true;
    MessageBox.Show("s");
}
```

4. Specify a ViewModel for your window:

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <nameSpace:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

**UPDATED**

5. Change `ItemsSource` binding statement like this (I changed (s)tudents to (S)tudents):

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding Students, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. But even though I did the same thing, when I pressed the button, the data didn't appear on the data grid screen...

Comment: I created a sample project with your codes and with dummy data and it worked for me with the changes as commented above. I suggest use breakpoint to find the problem.

Comment: I also checked the brake points but couldn't find any problems.
Can you check my code file?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asz035i2mCB94WB3LnePxfwPrkeU?e=KxxaNp

Comment: I just changed the students to Students and it's worked. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have a further question: Can you tell me what to do with mvvm when I'm trying to add data directly into the database from within the data grid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you have done it in the code you haven't pasted here, but you don't seem to have set the DataContext of the MainWindow to MyViewModel.

Insert this into MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```